# How to create a package in oracle that is having many materialized views

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am having a list of materialized views. I want to create a package that will contain all views inside this so that whenever needed I can refresh package.

Comment: A package is not a container for materialized views.  Perhaps you mean to ask how to create a refresh group, not a package?

Comment: Yes I want to create a refresh group, but my client asked me to create  a package having a procedure that will refresh all materialized views.

Comment: Do you want to create a refresh group and a packaged procedure that refreshes that refresh group?  Or do you want to create a packaged procedure that refreshes each materialized view in turn?  Do all the materialized views need to be transactionally consistent with each other?  Or can they all be independently refreshed?

Comment: First I need to find all materialized views that are dependent on a table. then create a procedure that will refresh each materialized view and finally put this procedure in a package.

Comment: OK.  So you don't need the refreshes to be transactionally consistent?  One materialized view can reflect transactions that another materialized view may not?  @everno gave you an example of refreshing every materialized view you own in turn.  Is that what you want?  What does "dependent on a table" mean to you?  Are you talking about a local table (i.e. you're using materialized views for aggregation)?  Or a remote table (i.e. you're using materialized views for replication)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the packages as per below:

```
---- Creating specification
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SM_OWN.mv_refr_pkg
IS
        PROCEDURE PROC_MV_REFRESH;

END mv_refr_pkg;
/

---- Creating BODY
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SM_OWN.mv_refr_pkg
IS

PROCEDURE PROC_MV_REFRESH
IS
BEGIN

FOR mv_name IN
  (SELECT NAME
   FROM sys.dba_dependencies
   WHERE OWNER = 'SM_OWN'
     AND referenced_name='SM_TRANSFER'
     AND TYPE='MATERIALIZED VIEW')

        LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(systimestamp || ' Refreshing materialized view SM_OWN.'||mv_name.Name );
                DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('SM_OWN.'||mv_name.Name);
        END LOOP;

END PROC_MV_REFRESH;
END;
/


How to Run:
set serveroutput on ;
execute SM_OWN.mv_refr_pkg.PROC_MV_REFRESH;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to create a code that refreshes all the mviews in your schema?

something like

```
Create procedure mv_ref is
begin
 for i in (select mview_name from user_mviews) loop
  dbms_mview.(i.mview_name,'f'); -- or whatever method you use
 end loop;
end;
```

I don't have Oracle installed here - so if it does not compile, you should be able to get the idea from it...

Comment: Thanks evenro. I have crated a procedure like mentioned by you. It is working fine. Now I want to call this procedure inside a package. Finally I can refresh package.